# HADOOP java.net.connection exception

Tags: java, exception, hadoop

```
hduser@master:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar pi 30 100
Number of Maps  = 30
Samples per Map = 100
15/09/27 20:21:42 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Wrote input for Map #2
Wrote input for Map #3
Wrote input for Map #4
Wrote input for Map #5
Wrote input for Map #6
Wrote input for Map #7
Wrote input for Map #8
Wrote input for Map #9
Wrote input for Map #10
Wrote input for Map #11
Wrote input for Map #12
Wrote input for Map #13
Wrote input for Map #14
Wrote input for Map #15
Wrote input for Map #16
Wrote input for Map #17
Wrote input for Map #18
Wrote input for Map #19
Wrote input for Map #20
Wrote input for Map #21
Wrote input for Map #22
Wrote input for Map #23
Wrote input for Map #24
Wrote input for Map #25
Wrote input for Map #26
Wrote input for Map #27
Wrote input for Map #28
Wrote input for Map #29
Starting Job
15/09/27 20:21:47 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/10.42.0.109:8032
15/09/27 20:21:48 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 30
15/09/27 20:21:48 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:30
15/09/27 20:21:49 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1443365451043_0001
15/09/27 20:21:49 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1443365451043_0001
15/09/27 20:21:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1443365451043_0001/
15/09/27 20:21:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1443365451043_0001
15/09/27 20:21:57 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1443365451043_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/09/27 20:21:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/09/27 20:22:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 20% reduce 0%
15/09/27 20:22:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 40% reduce 0%
15/09/27 20:22:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 53% reduce 0%
15/09/27 20:22:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 57% reduce 0%
15/09/27 20:22:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 57% reduce 19%
15/09/27 20:22:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 60% reduce 19%
15/09/27 20:22:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 60% reduce 20%
15/09/27 20:22:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 73% reduce 20%
15/09/27 20:23:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 73% reduce 24%
15/09/27 20:23:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 90% reduce 24%
15/09/27 20:23:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 24%
15/09/27 20:23:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/09/27 20:23:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1443365451043_0001 completed successfully
15/09/27 20:23:53 INFO mapred.ClientServiceDelegate: Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
15/09/27 20:23:54 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:23:55 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:23:56 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:23:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:23:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:23:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:01 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:02 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:03 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:04 INFO mapred.ClientServiceDelegate: Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
15/09/27 20:24:05 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:06 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:07 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:08 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:09 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:10 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:11 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:12 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:13 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:14 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:14 INFO mapred.ClientServiceDelegate: Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
15/09/27 20:24:15 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:16 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:17 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:18 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:19 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:20 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:21 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:22 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:23 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/09/27 20:24:24 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/10.42.0.109 to 0.0.0.0:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getJobCounters(ClientServiceDelegate.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getJobCounters(YARNRunner.java:564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$7.run(Job.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$7.run(Job.java:764)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getCounters(Job.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.monitorAndPrintJob(Job.java:1389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.estimatePi(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.run(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.main(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:363)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/10.42.0.109 to 0.0.0.0:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.getCounters(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.client.MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getCounters(MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:166)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:323)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 36 more
```

How to solve this.Please help
I am new to hadoop.
On typing jps in master i get the following output on master node

```
$ jps
NameNode
SecondaryNameNode
DataNode
```

DataNode on all slave nodes.
I tried to read the apache documentation but was not able to understand.Please i have a project submission.

Comment: Check ip address of all three services in hosts file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508847/connectexception-connection-refused-when-run-mapreduce-in-hadoop

Comment: A similar question has already been asked and answered. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35915354/758673

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pig and Hadoop connection error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061100/pig-and-hadoop-connection-error)