# Hadoop pig connection error - historyserver won't start

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Basically have a problem that has come up before: The same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930644/connection-error-in-apache-pig) for example.

I get a connect error if I try to work a pig script.

Looking into it, indeed the history server is not running. Seemed easy enough to fix. But then... It was not.

Sadly, I tried to start the history server in both ways I am aware of:

1) Go into the hadoop sbin and work with:

```
   mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```

Which results in:

```
  bash: mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh: command not found
```

Even though when I do an ls of the directory mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh is indeed listed.

2) simply do:

```
  sudo service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver start
```

Which will at least don't throw a "not found" error. But instead:

```
  Failed to start Hadoop historyserver. Return value: 1      [FAILED]
```

With the logfile linked sadly turning out to be completely empty.

Hence: Same problem, but the solutions known to me seem not to work.

I am pretty sure I am overlooking something - as I am pretty sure I have had the same problem with a different setup a year ago. But I fail to remember how I solved it back then.

I am running the newest version of hadoop (2.7.2) on a centos VM with CentOS 6.5 on VMWare player.

Comment: try sh mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver or bash mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver or ./mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver, did you get something different than   'bash: mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh: command not found' doing this ?

Comment: @Koffee Indeed this actually has some effect. I guess I know the problem, just not sure what to do to fix it. It says "cannot create dir", "missing operant after 'tom'" and then /bin/mapred no such file or directory. I would guess it is the later making the biggest problem. But I am confused why it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead  (./mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver ) and verify it by running jps command from terminal!

Answer (score 0):

**I am using CentOS 6.2 and doing this worked for me**

- edit the .bashrc, using the command:
  `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`
- and add the path to your hadoop sbin:
  `export PATH=$PATH:$/<user>/.../hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin`
- now close the terminal and reopen it.
- run the command:
  `source ~/.bashrc`
- now try running the history server:
  `mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver`