# Can't run a file that exist

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, terminal, apache-pig

Can't run a file that exist. I am unsure why this is giving me an error. 
At the moment I am trying to fix this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930644/connection-error-in-apache-pig) However, I can't seem to get pass this step.

```
a@a-VirtualBox:~/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/sbin$ ls
distribute-exclude.sh  kms.sh                   start-balancer.sh    stop-balancer.sh    yarn-daemons.sh
hadoop-daemon.sh       mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh  start-dfs.sh         stop-dfs.sh
hadoop-daemons.sh      refresh-namenodes.sh     start-secure-dns.sh  stop-secure-dns.sh
hdfs-config.sh         slaves.sh                start-yarn.sh        stop-yarn.sh
httpfs.sh              start-all.sh             stop-all.sh          yarn-daemon.sh
a@a-VirtualBox:~/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/sbin$ mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh: command not found
a@a-VirtualBox:~/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/sbin$ hdfs dfs mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh: Unknown command
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should run this command like this:

```
./mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh
```

or like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:`pwd` mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh
```

The second one cannot collide with another programs that could be in "/usr/bin" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `./program-name.sh arguments` to execute a program in the working directory.

Using `program-name.sh arguments` implies that it is covered by the `PATH` variable, and a couple other things.